# "prometheus" error during Jenkins helm install

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I try to install Jenkins on Googe Cloud (GKE v. 1.27) using Helm chart from https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jenkins
The installation is stuck in the status "Pods are pending" with a lot of errors like:

```
error   scrape/scrape.go:1202   Scrape commit failed    {"kind": "receiver", "name": "prometheus", "scrape_pool": "gpu-maintenance-handler", "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8526/metrics", "err": "process_start_time_seconds metric is missing"}"
```

This occurs, even though controller.prometheus.enabled is explicitly defined as false in the value.yaml file.